# Why does my Python code not update one of my variables?

Tags: python

I have a body that I want to accelerate in a straight line through an iterative process, however when I look at my variables it never adds the updated velocity into the velocity array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 9.81  # Gravity
pa = 1.2  # Air density
m = 250  # mass of bike
h = 0.69  # centre of mass height
ha = 0.69  # height of centre pressure
w = 1.5  # wheelbase
b = 0.73  # longitudinal distance of centre of mass
CdA = 0.2  # drag coefficient
PMax = 180000  # max power
ux = 1.2  # Longitudinal friction coefficient
uy = 1.44  # Lateral friction coefficient

St1Length = 400

ds = 40
vel = np.zeros(St1Length//ds)
s = np.linspace(0, St1Length, len(vel)) 

while s[-1] < St1Length:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * vel[-1]**2
    Ap = ((PMax / ((m * vel[-1]) + 1e-9)) - (Fd / m)) / g  
    yw = 0
    Aw = (((b * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) - ((Fd * ha) / (m * h))) / g
    Wheelie_Min = np.minimum(Ap, Aw)
    vel_new = np.sqrt(vel[-1]**2 + 2*Wheelie_Min*ds)
    vel = np.append(vel, vel_new)

    s_new = s[-1] + ds 
    s = np.append(s, s_new)

plt.plot(s, vel)
plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity (m/s)')
plt.show()
```

What follows is a graph that looks like this:
[image]

And this is what my variable list looks like:
[image]

This is probably an easy fix but I can't seem to see what is wrong.

What I am expecting is for the array to update and the Velocity on the graph to increase due to acceleration.

Comment: What's not shown: what is the value of `vel_new`?

Comment: Just ran your code and found out that `s[-1]==400.0` and `St1Length==400`. Your while loop never runs.

Comment: I recommend you set a breakpoint and step through your code a bit. Look at what each line is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is updated because `s[-1] = 400` (i.e. `s[-1]` is never <400). This code should fix the problems.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 9.81  # Gravity
pa = 1.2  # Air density
m = 250  # mass of bike
h = 0.69  # centre of mass height
ha = 0.69  # height of centre pressure
w = 1.5  # wheelbase
b = 0.73  # longitudinal distance of centre of mass
CdA = 0.2  # drag coefficient
PMax = 180000  # max power
ux = 1.2  # Longitudinal friction coefficient
uy = 1.44  # Lateral friction coefficient

St1Length = 400

ds = 40
vel = [0.]
s = [0.]

while s[-1] < St1Length:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * vel[-1]**2
    Ap = ((PMax / ((m * vel[-1]) + 1e-9)) - (Fd / m)) / g  
    yw = 0
    Aw = (((b * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) - ((Fd * ha) / (m * h))) / g
    Wheelie_Min = np.minimum(Ap, Aw)
    vel_new = np.sqrt(vel[-1]**2 + 2*Wheelie_Min*ds)
    vel.append(vel_new)

    s_new = s[-1] + ds 
    s.append(s_new)

plt.plot(s, vel)
plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity (m/s)')
plt.show()
```